# marker.isVisible is true, but no marker is showing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have a map and I add a marker on it when firebase massage received.
sometimes, when I turn off my screen and then turn it on, i can't see my marker.

i have the following code in onResume:

```
 if (situation_ == 3) {

            if (marker == null){
                Log.i("Logit", "is null");
            }else{
                Log.i("Logit", String.valueOf(marker.isVisible()));
            }

            if (marker == null || !marker.isVisible()) {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String Lat = pref.read_pref_info("usera");
                        String Lng = pref.read_pref_info("userb");
                        marker_op = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(Lat), Double.valueOf(Lng)))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.marker));
                        try {
                            Marker = mMap.addMarker(marker_op);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
```

so I can see in Logs that marker is not null and marker.isVisible returns true.
but i can't see any marker on map and it doesn't go in this if line:

```
if (marker == null || !marker.isVisible()) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#isVisible()).

```
public boolean isVisible ()
```

> Gets the visibility setting of this marker. **Note that this does not
>   indicate whether the marker is within the screen's viewport**. It
>   indicates whether the marker will be drawn if it is contained in the
>   screen's viewport.